# Wifi connection problem

Tags: wireless, broadcom, 14.04, wired

i just installed ubuntu 14.04 and when i'am connected with wifi i can't post or register on any site or forum
there is no problem when iam using wired connection

i've got broadcom 43142

Comment: Your case is solved in the marked question. The BCM43142 is the 14e4:4365.